# Angular UI Bootstrap progress directive binding on Orbicular attr

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've done a bunch of searching and reading on this one but have come up at a loss.  Basically, we have two plugins.  Orbicular and Angular UI Boostrap.  Orbicular is inserted using the following:

```
<orbicular progress="downloaded" total="size">Text in the circle</orbicular>
```

What happens is, UI Bootstrap then tries to bind to the 'progress' attr and I get:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [orbicular, progress]
asking for new/isolated scope on: <div class="co-circle-progress"
progress="match.score" total="100">
```

It seems like there should be some way to protect your attributes so directives don't bind to attributes of another plugin/directive.  Any suggestions are appreciated. I could just be using the wrong search terms.

Comment: Interesting problem. I don't know of a fix that doesn't involve tweaking the source for one of the plugins to fix the namespace (either by changing the name of the attribute bound to the orbicular isolate scope or restricting the ui bootstrap directive to element only). I would like to know if there is another solution, though.

Comment: For now, I did a PR on Orbicular.  I don't think there is a way to protect another directives attributes short of naming.  It does have some implications on how people write plugins.  It would be good to namespace them so common words like 'progress' don't get bound against.